# How to build a Javascript Array Delta

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, algorithm

I have an array of arrays where the position of the value is important in that this data is used to ultimately layout a grid.

```
[[a,b,c,d],[a,b,c,d][a,b,c,d],[a,b,c,d]] // Original data
```

Based on an action, values within this "dataset" can change, but the size will never change.

```
[[a,b,c,d],[a,b,b,b][a,c,c,c],[a,b,c,d]] // Modified data
```

What I'd like to do is to return a dataset that only contains the delta values:

```
[[null,null,null,null,],[null,null,b,b],[null,c,null,c],[null,null,null,null,]]
```

Now, I do always know the max X and Y of the dataset, and could simply loop through the original dataset, comparing it's value to the corresponding value and build a new array, but it seems like there could be a more efficient way to accomplish this.

That said, my js-fu is minimal at best, and that's why I'm brining the problem here. Are there any language provided methods for accomplishing this? Suggested approaches? etc?

Comment: If you don't know anything about the two arrays and the made modification then you will have to loop. To make it more efficient, what do you already know about the modification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of array mapping should do the trick.

**Here's a fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/C8jnr/

Given the following:

```
var arr_A = [[a,b,c,d],[a,b,c,d],[a,b,c,d],[a,b,c,d]];
var arr_B = [[a,b,c,d],[a,b,b,b],[a,c,c,c],[a,b,c,d]];

function deltaArrays(arr1, arr2)
{
    return arr1.map(function(el_arr,i,arr){
        return el_arr.map(function(el, j){
            return (el == arr2[i][j]) ? null : arr2[i][j];
        });
    });
}
```

Calling deltaArrays on the two will yield the expected delta array;

```
deltaArrays(arr_A, arr_B) = [[null,null,null,null,],[null,null,b,b],[null,c,null,c],[null,null,null,null,]]
```

Comment: That is much more concise, yet readable than what I wrote. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a built in way to do this.  Your best bet is to loop through each of the array elements and compare them with the new array, adding it to a list/dictionary if it is different.